# End of line marker in Windows virtual machine running on Mac OSX

Tags: eol

What end of line (eoln) marker do I use if I'm running a Windows 7 virtual machine in Parallels Desktop on Mac OSX?  The file is saved in a Mac directory but accessed only through Windows.

Comment: Are you encountering a problem, or are you asking about best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows is Windows - the newline does *not* change based on the physical hardware.

The Parallels VM *"emulates"* (via a form of [paravirtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization)) the guest hardware so that Windows doesn't even "know" it's running in OS X.

Now the 'virtual folder mapping' makes the question a bit different (as Parallels maps the folder at a higher level then the core emulation layer, IIRC) but the result is the same. Parallels does *not* rewrite newlines across the boundary; and Windows *programs* (by convention) use Windows EOLs.

Since the application is a "windows program", I would follow the Windows EOL convention; except when such violates an existing contract or specification.

Answer (score 0):

If it is used from Windows, use Windows conventions (`\r\n`).